# Help identifying the make and model of my bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

What kind of BMX do I have?  This is embossed on the top of the toptube, in the casting for the lugg.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read this https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: Well, its not a Haro as per the top cap's label.   I tried sketching the outline and feeding that into google image search.  There were plenty of results but nothing relevant.   A clear photo of the whole bike from the right-hand side would help.